# Electrical Engineering Prelab - Absolute value of gate voltage

Tags: voltage, resistance, thermistor, homework, electrical

[image]

A. In the circuit in the figure, the thermistor resistance is 50 kΩ. What is the absolute value of the gate voltage (voltage at node G) versus ground?

B. How does your result change if the thermistor resistance decreases and becomes equal to 30 kΩ?

---

I'm a little confused because is says the thermistor is "50 kΩ - 30 kΩ" which would be 20 kΩ... You think that is supposed to just signify both parts of the question (in which case a slash would make more sense instead of a minus sign I suppose. If I had to give an educated guess, I would say -10 V for both parts? I'm honestly unsure.

Comment: Range of possible resistance.  Don't be so literal!

Answer (score 2):

That's not a minus sign. It's a dash. It's saying the thermistor has a range from 50 K to 30K (and, apparently, a negative temperature coefficient).

So, your task is to compute the gate voltage when the thermistor is at 50K, and again when it's at 30K.

Since you just want to compute the gate voltage, look only at the left block of your schematic. What sort of circuit does that look like on its own? I.e., given something like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fDwtP9.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

What voltage do you get at Vout based on V1, R1, and R2?

Comment: Oh that makes sense; thanks for that clarification. The reason I said -10 V is to balance out the positive 10 V. Am I on the right track with this? Although I realize I am not taking into account the resistance, which is why I wouldn't be surprised if that answer is incorrect

Comment: I'm sorry. I'm sure that hint should be more than helpful but I'm still stumped. Is it just using a formula?

Comment: @Hello: That's generally known as a "voltage divider". And yes, there's a formula for the output from a voltage divider.

Comment: Oh! How does 1.935 V and 2.857 V sound?

Comment: @Hello: Sounds a *whole* lot better than -10 volts.